# Casting a value with CCSID to match another hexidecimal in db2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a query that works manually in my editor for DB2:

```
SELECT          *
FROM            TableOne T1
WHERE           CAST(T1 . IDENITIFIER AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535) = x'0213725502A3BC45706AEE6001';
```

However, When I try this with the hex value being a param, it isn't working:

```
    SELECT          *
    FROM            TableOne T1
    WHERE           CAST(T1 . IDENITIFIER AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535) = x':identifier'
```

How can I either properly append the x to the sting value/param in order to have a dynamic query where I can inject the identifier? Or is there another way I can get the same result by casting this origin value with the ccsid to match?

Comment: Try [HEXTORAW](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscavarbinaryformat.htm) function.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein will this work for the IBM Iseries version 7 on the 400?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein hextoraw(:Value) executes but returns no results, where my intial query returns a result

Comment: Try `CAST(HEXTORAW(:Value) AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535)` with a string constant `0213725502A3BC45706AEE6001`.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I tried ```CAST(HEXTORAW(T . IDENTIFIER) AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535) = '0213725502A3BB8F2149C82001'``` but it says Argument 01 of function VARBINARY_FORMAT not valid

Comment: `... WHERE CAST(T1.IDENITIFIER AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535) = CAST(HEXTORAW(:Value) AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535)`

Comment: @MarkBarinstein YES!!! Thank you so much, that worked! I'll accept an answer whenever you make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the string `0213725502A3BC45706AEE6001` (hex representation of `x'0213725502A3BC45706AEE6001'`) as a parameter value in the following statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableOne T1
WHERE CAST(T1.IDENITIFIER AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535) = CAST(HEXTORAW(:identifier) AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535)
```